# Estimating CAN Bus Load

Tags: can

It's my first time doing this kind of task, so I'm a little unsecure if my method is right.

Heres my setup and what I`ve done so far.

I`m using a PCAN USB (Peak System) + PCAN View tracing a J1939 Network using extended identifiers.
The application has no numerical indication about the bus load, only status like bus ok, heavy bus... So I decided to convert the trace record into a CSV and then analyzing it with Python.

Once I had it converted, I was interested in get 4 fields of information: message ID, data size (how many data bytes in that message), how many times that message was sent, and the message itself.

Cycletime was calculated as the total recording time divided by how many times that message was sent.

Message Size was calculated considering:

Start of Frame - 1 bit

Identifier A - 11 bits

Identifier B - 18 bits

Substitute Remote Request - 1 bit

ID Extension Bit - 1

Remote Transmission Request - 1

Reserved Bits - 2

Data Length Code - 4

Data Field - 0-64 bits

Cyclic Redundance Check - 15

CRC Delimiter - 1

ACK Slot - 1

ACK Delimiter - 1

End of Frame - 7

________________________________TOTAL (considering a 8 byte message): 128bits
Load was calculated as 128bits*1000/cycletime

% of Bandwidth was calculated as Load/250000

Am I Missing Something?

Is there another method that's more accurate?

Answer (score 2):

To estimate the bus load you need two pieces of information for each msg on the bus

1. Total message bits ( data bits + protocol)
2. Message rate

You also need the Bus Rate.

You first need to determine the total bits consumed (bps) for each message. This is **message total bit** x **message rate**. The summation provides the total bits in bps.  This can then be compared with the bus rate.

say you had three messages
ID1 = 55bits every 1ms   = 55kbps
ID2 = 87bits every 10ms  = 8.7kbps
ID3 = 111bits every 1s   = 0.11kbps

total kbps is therefore 63.81kbps.

thus the bus load is

- 25.5%  at 250kbps
- 12.8% at 500kbps
- 6.4% at 1Mbps

so if you have one message that is 128bits being sent at a rate of 1ms, that is 128kbps. On a bus that supports 250kbps, this is a bus load of 51%

Comment: The way I did gave me same values as yours.

I'm a little more curious to find out if this method is valid and if it describes the real scenario on my CAN Bus.

 I want find out If my bus is malfunctioning because I'm having some guys popping out of the network, so I presume something is going wrong, although my study gave me a Load Bus of 25,75%.

Comment: I have one doubt over here. when calculating the number of bits whether i need to consider the bits in the data frame only(8 bytes)or all the bits in the CAN frame such as message identifier,RTR,DLC etc everything ? @JonRB

Comment: bits in the dataframe, including bit stuffing